# Oracle PL/SQL: how to get the stack trace, package name and procedure name

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, stack-trace

Sometimes the exception returns something like: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error:
character string buffer too small".

It's not so readable since it doesn't report neither the table, the column and the value it tried to write.

it would be useful to get the current procedure name at the moment the Exception happened or is catched.

How can I obtain that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You probably want [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1003874) function

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace procedure p1
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Error 1', true );
  5* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p2
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5    p1;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p2;
  3  exception
  4    when others then
  5      dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace );
  6  end;
  7  /
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P1", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P2", line 5
ORA-06512: at
line 2


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 15):

I use the combination of [DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73242) and [DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73241). (Improving the answer of Justin Cave)

```
when others then
  Dbms_Output.put_line ( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK() );
  Dbms_Output.put_line ( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE() );
```

This gives the error on the first line and the stack on the following lines: (output from the example given by Justin Cave)

```
ORA-20001: Error 1
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.X1", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.X2", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Better use Dbms_Output.PUT, as the error stack/trace already contain a new line character.

Answer (score 11):

Or try [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i997163)

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use [`DBMS_DEBUG.PRINT_BACKTRACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_debug.htm#i1009079)