# Stored procedures with triggers oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

i have a store procedure which is called by 4 different trigger
is it possible to get trigger's information like name when the procedure is executed.

i can do it by passing a extra parameter to the procedure,
is there any other option?
i am using oracle 11g.
Thanks

Comment: You can add an additional parameter to the procedure to pass this trigger name.

Comment: Unfortunately, triggers apparently do not appear in the stack backtrace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032373/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-get-the-stack-trace-package-name-and-procedure-name how to get the stacktrace but in my tests, the trigger name is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function `dbms_utility.format_call_stack` which is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73240):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table test_table (n number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure test_procedure as
  2  begin
  3     dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace trigger test_trigger_insert
  2  before insert on test_table
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5     test_procedure;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger test_trigger_delete
  2  before delete on test_table
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5     test_procedure;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> rem direct execution of the procedure
SQL> exec test_procedure;
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x2bc2f1ca0         3  procedure YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_PROCEDURE
0x31a218568         1
anonymous block


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> rem procedure called by trigger test_trigger_insert
SQL> insert into test_table (n) values (42);
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x2bc2f1ca0         3  procedure YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_PROCEDURE
0x2adc40fb0         2
YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_TRIGGER_INSERT


1 row created.

SQL> rem procedure called by trigger test_trigger_delete
SQL> delete from test_table where n = 42;
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x2bc2f1ca0         3  procedure YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_PROCEDURE
0x2f10ffd28         2
YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_TRIGGER_DELETE


1 row deleted.
```

Comment: got my problem solved,thank you @marco baldelli for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

If your trigger is called My_Trigger you can try this:

```
SELECT Trigger_type, Triggering_event, Table_name
   FROM USER_TRIGGERS
   WHERE Trigger_name = 'My_Trigger';
```